Problem with c++ code or my file management
I am new to C++ and I can't understand what is wrong with my code. I am using code block for my project and I don't even know how I can see the error message. So I know what is wrong but I dont know why as all the files are normaly set up. This part of the code is just supose to make a chesboard like background. It tells me there is an error at the line 11  sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(600 / size, 600 / size));
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int size = 8;
bool loop = true;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Echec Dames");

void drawBoard(int size) {
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(600 / size, 600 / size));
    bool colorSwitch = false;

    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
        for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
            rect.setPosition(n * 600 / size, r * 600 / size);
            rect.setFillColor(colorSwitch ? sf::Color::White : sf::Color::Black);
            window.draw(rect);
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
    }
}

I tried looking up the syntax but I couldn't finc any mistakes. Same with the modules or library (I don't know how it is called). I at least expected to has an errore message but I can't figure out how to see them.

First question: What error message?

Knowing which line the error is on is no help if we don't know what the error is.

Tip: Instead of smashing around with a separate boolean variable, consider how you can use modulo math to get the black/white status of a square. It's generally (x + y) % 2, or in your case (n + r) % 2. To simplify your code you could also make an array of checkerboard values, then just color[(n + r) % 2] and be done with it, no ternary needed! As a bonus this easily scales to checkerboards with >2 colors.

If you're really "new to C++" then continue to learn the basics first before trying an advanced project including graphics. Also spend some time to really get to know your IDE of choice.

If it's a runtime error, then I would note that if you were passing in 0 as a value for the size parameter, that line would probably throw up a nice division-by-zero exception.

"I don't even know how I can see the error message" -- Maybe you should ask about this before diving into your project. Start a new project with something simple that contains an obvious error, like int main() { return this_identifier_is_not_defined; }, and figure out where the error message appears. (Ask a [tag:codeblocks] question that emphasizes you know what the error is, but not where to see the error message?)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I'm using Qtcreator with sfml library, Mingw qmake for this response. First I'd like to try supplement the code with a main function to work properly. without changing anything in the code for now.
The main function in question looks like this:
int main()
{
    // create the window
    //sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "My window");

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);
        drawBoard(5);
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

This main function is more or less the copy-pasted version from the official SFML website tutorial section of how to start with SFML, with the only differences being the commented out window variable creation as well as your chessboard function added in the display section of the while loop.
Source: SFML tutorial Link
The following code runs smoothly displaying a 5x5 chessboard window. I was not able to recreate your error/problem with the rectangle. The only thing I've noticed is that using your function without this main loop, doesn't show the screen like intended. To have a continuous view of such a chessboard, an infinite loop like the one in the main function is needed.

That being said, the code in itself isn't ideal. I suggest dividing it up into parts and integrating them into the main function provided for best performance.
Lets first divide the function into separate important parts:

The creation of the object

int size = 8;
bool loop = true;

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Echec Dames");
...
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(600 / size, 600 / size));
    bool colorSwitch = false;
...


The positioning of the object

for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
        for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
            rect.setPosition(n * 600 / size, r * 600 / size);
            rect.setFillColor(colorSwitch ? sf::Color::White : sf::Color::Black);
            ...
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
    }


The drawing of the object

window.draw(rect);

Creation:
What you're doing in the function is you create one rectangle, set its position, draw it on the screen, then move it, draw it again, as many times as you need to, in every single frame of the code. Creating objects, and moving them like that in every frame isn't exactly optimal for your program. Let's switch this up by moving all the objects that you'll be using before the infinite while loop, to not waste time each frame, and while we're there let's also take the variables inside the main function. No need in having them be global variables.
The code will now look something like this:
int main()
{
    // create the window
    int size = 8;
    bool loop = true;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Echec Dames");
    sf::RectangleShape rect(sf::Vector2f(600 / size, 600 / size));

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);
        drawBoard(5);
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}

Next it would be best if we got rid of the movement inside the drawing section, as the bigger the chessboard will be the more times the rectangle will have to be moved per frame (size^2 times more or less). To do this the idea has to slightly changed. Instead of having one rectangle that constantly moves around, why not have multiple rectangles stationary in their relative positions. That way the only thing the program will have to do is draw them. You can use any sort of container for this. I'll be using an std::vector. A double std::vector will enable each rectangle in the grid to have its own 'x' and 'y' coordinate making it easier to set and draw and manage with other 2 dimensional aspects later on.
int main()
{
    // create the window
    int size = 8;
    bool loop = true;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Echec Dames");
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> vec;

    ...
    return 0;
}

Positioning and parameter setting:
The vector itself is just a place for the objects to be located in, we have to create and add them to the container. Let's change your function a little bit to accommodate this.
void setBoard(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> &vec, int size) {
    bool colorSwitch = false;
    float sizeOfRect = 600.f / size;
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
        vec.emplace_back();
        for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
            sf::RectangleShape tmp;
            tmp.setSize({sizeOfRect, sizeOfRect});
            tmp.setPosition(n * sizeOfRect, r * sizeOfRect);
            tmp.setFillColor(colorSwitch ? sf::Color::White : sf::Color::Black);
            vec[n].emplace_back(tmp);
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
    }
}

The above function takes in the vector and size parameters, and creates a rectangle for each size by size element in the grid setting its size, position and color. Notice the calculation of the size of each rect in the vector is done with one of the values being a float. If both are integers you may run into some 0 values (for example when the size of the board is higher than the size of the window. This isn't probable but still a safe assumption).
Drawing:
Now that the grid is set in a more optimal fashion drawing it can be done with a simple draw function in a double loop as shown in the code below.
void drawBoard(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> &vec, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < (int)vec.size(); ++n) {
        for (int r = 0; r < (int)vec[0].size(); ++r) {
            window.draw(vec[n][r]);
        }
    }
}

Finalizing:
The set function will the be used just after the creation of the objects, and just before the start of the infinite loop. The draw function has to be used in the draw section of the main loop. Splitting your function into pieces like this makes the code a little bit more optimal, working but cleaner to read as well. Hope this helps. If you have any questions or you found mistakes I made please ask. Below is the final full code. Tested it and it works.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

void setBoard(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> &vec, int size) {
    bool colorSwitch = false;
    float sizeOfRect = 600.f / size;
    for (int n = 0; n < size; ++n) {
        vec.emplace_back();
        for (int r = 0; r < size; ++r) {
            sf::RectangleShape tmp;
            tmp.setSize({sizeOfRect, sizeOfRect});
            tmp.setPosition(n * sizeOfRect, r * sizeOfRect);
            tmp.setFillColor(colorSwitch ? sf::Color::White : sf::Color::Black);
            vec[n].emplace_back(tmp);
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
        if (size % 2 == 0) {
            colorSwitch = !colorSwitch;
        }
    }
}

void drawBoard(std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> &vec, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
    for (int n = 0; n < (int)vec.size(); ++n) {
        for (int r = 0; r < (int)vec[0].size(); ++r) {
            window.draw(vec[n][r]);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    // create the window
    int size = 5;
    bool loop = true;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600, 600), "Echec Dames");
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>> vec;
    setBoard(vec, size);

    // run the program as long as the window is open
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // clear the window with black color
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        // draw everything here...
        // window.draw(...);
        drawBoard(vec, window);
        // end the current frame
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}



